# Erro ao receber json de objetos Android Studio

Tags: android, web-service, android-studio

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com problemas para receber um array de objetos e mostrar em ListView no android. No caso a classe que esta dando erro é essa:

```
public class HTTPCarregaLista extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Documento>> {

private final String filial;

public HTTPCarregaLista(String filial) {
    this.filial = filial;
}

@Override
protected List<Documento> doInBackground(Void... Void) {

    List<Documento> docs = new ArrayList<Documento>();

    StringBuilder resposta = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.meuwebservice.com" + this.filial);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.connect();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            resposta.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Collections.singletonList(new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), Documento.class));

}
```

No caso a linha:

```
return Collections.singletonList(new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), Documento.class));
```

Dispara esta Exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Minha classe Documento:

```
public class Documento implements Serializable {
private long Cd_Filial;
private String Cd_Cod_Doc;
private String Dt_Movimento;
private String Cd_Cod_Produto;
private String Cd_Localizacao;
private String Nr_Documento;
private String Qtd_Recebida;
private String Qtd_Aceita;
private String Qtd_Vendida;
private String Qtd_Perda;
private String Qtd_Devolver;
private String Qtd_Devolvida;

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Filial: " + getCd_Filial()
            + "\nCódigo: " + getCd_Cod_Doc()
            + "\nLocalização: " + getCd_Localizacao()
            + "\nData: " + getDt_Movimento();

}

}
```

E este é o retorno do meu webservice:

```
[
 {"Cd_Filial":"1","Dt_Movimento":"01/01/2019 00:00:00",
 "Cd_Cod_Doc":"01","Cd_Cod_Produto":"01",
 "Cd_Localizacao":"01","Nr_Documento":"01","Qtd_Recebida":"10,000",
 "Qtd_Aceita":"0,000","Qtd_Vendida":"0,000","Qtd_Perda":"0,000",
 "Qtd_Devolver":"0,000","Qtd_Devolvida":"0,000"}
]
```

Alguem pode dizer o que estou fazendo errado ou dar alguma dica com relação ao problema? agradeço desde já a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repare que no erro está te informando onde está o problema, é esperado um object, mas está recebendo um array no json.

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
Gson mGson = new Gson();
mDocumento = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response.body().getAsJsonArray(), Documento[].class));
```

Comment: Leonardo Figueiredo, muito obrigado pela sua resposta, resolveu meu problema.